# Further explanation for Rudin's exercise 17 in chapter 1

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vectors

The exercise is as follows: Suppose $k \geq 3, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^k, \left|x - y\right| = d > 0, r > 0$. Show that

a.) If $2d > r$, there are infinitely many $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\left|z - x\right| = \left|z - y\right| = r$.

b.) If $2d = r$, there is exactly one such $z$.

c.) If $2r < d$, there is not such $z$.

The part is is the easiest of the three, as $\left|x - y + z - z\right| \leq \left|x - z\right| + \left|z - y\right| = \left|z - x\right| + \left|z - y\right| \Longleftrightarrow 2r < d \leq 2r$, thus no such $z$ exists.

However I can honestly say that even after reading the model solution of the exercise, I still don't really understand what is done and why in the part a.), and part b.) for that matter. The outline of the model solution for a.) is that one starts by considering a vector $w$ which satisfies $w\cdot(x-y) = 0, \left|w\right|^2 = r^2 - \frac{d^2}{4}$. Then as the first equation defines a plane, all but one components of $w$ are arbitrary. Then if $w$ is a non-zero solution there exists a unique positive real $t$ s.t. $tw$ is also a solution. Then, as in total at least two components of the $w$ and $tw$ can vary independently, we can have them equal some ratio (not sure what, the author does not specify). Moreover as the ratio is not affected multiplication by $t$, there are infinitely many ratios and thus infinitely many solutions. Then we can finally see that for each such solution $z = \frac{1}{2}(x + y) + w$ is a solution which satisfies the required condition.

Edit: My question is specifically how can we see that such a $w$ satisfying the two given equations will yield a proper solution and moreover how should one be able to see to inspect the ratio of some components of the vector $w$ and its scaled counterpart $tw$?

Comment: Do you have a specific question to ask about the "model solution for a)" that you have typed above?

Comment: @311411 My bad. See the edited post for the specific question(s).